# Botframework TextPrompt how to send user input as postback

Tags: node.js, botframework

I built a bot that needs to ask the user for a password.
In my current implementation, the bot logic sends an event to the webchat-client to trigger the rendering of a password input field.

```
 const askPwd =
    {
        name: 'passwordInput',
        type: 'event'
    };
    await stepContext.context.sendActivity(askPwd);
    return await stepContext.prompt(SSD_PASSWORD_PROMPT);
```

In the webchat client, I use activity middleware to render the password input field (and hide the regular input field).

```
    const activityMiddleware = () => next => ({  activity, nextVisibleActivity, ...otherArgs }) => {
    const {  from: { role }, name, type } = activity;
    if (type === 'event' && name === 'passwordInput'){ return () => <PasswordInputActivity activity={activity} nextVisibleActivity={nextVisibleActivity} />;
    }}
```

This works but is confusing to the user. I would rather use the regular input field. I would be able to dynamically turn this into a password type field. The problem is that  the input is indeed masked but the password is shown in the  chat timeline (unmasked ofcourse).

Is there a way to use a text-prompt and send the input as postback to the bot-logic?

Comment: What do you mean by the "chat timeline"? If you are talking about an activity log / saved transcript, using a text-prompt and/or a postback won't alleviate this as those are also sent as activities. You would be better served intercepting the activity as it is received by the bot and encrypt the password before it is saved in your logs.

Comment: Additionally, as you can see from the code (I'm assuming you are using the "password-input" BotFramework-WebChat sample), the user's input is already sent as a postback, reference [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/05.custom-components/f.password-input/index.html#L102).

Comment: @StevenKanberg. Thanks fot the remarkts.
 I do use the password-input sample in one of my bots inclusing the postback. This is however  confusing to users. They use the sendbox for chatting with the chatbot all the time and as soon as they need to enter a password, they have to understand they need another field. I try to address this by hiding the sendbox (.main) and drawing a really nice passwork-input field but still,  I would rather have a consisent interface and use the sendbox for the password to (and have the password send as postback.

Comment: I can understand that maybe this isn't the behavior you are looking for, but this actually conforms to already established behavior. Both sign-in cards and OAuth prompts send as scrolling activities. It's not surprising that the password-input functions the same.

Comment: Tnx. I understand